# Don't understand why my NSString data is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, jsonmodel

Don't understand why my NSString data is null.

I am trying to parse a number string from a json website from my app. It works successfully, however when I am trying to show case that number in my view controller it reads null. I will post an example code for everyone to understand better.

Handler.m

```
JsonModel *jsonModel =[[JsonModel alloc]init];
jsonModel.idNumber = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"id"];
nslog(@"%@",jsonModel.idNumber);
```

JsonModel.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface JsonModelModel : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *idNumber;
```

JsonModel.m

```
#import "JsonModel.h"

@implementation JsonModel
@synthesize idNumber;
```

This part works successfully, I am able to get the necessary data parsed and the `NSLog` proves it. However, here comes the problem. P.S. idNumber is the NSString.

ViewController.m

```
-(void)method{
JsonModel *jsonModel =[[JsonModel alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonModel.idNumber);
}
```

The NSLog appears null for some reason. Even though the json data was parsed first then the method in view controller is called.I must be missing some small detail. Will appreciate it if someone helped me figure it out.

Comment: where is the property declaration?

Comment: This is unrelated, but note that you no longer need the `@synthesize` line—it works automatically.

Comment: Ok, I added the property declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a completely new, empty `JsonModel` object when you execute

```
JsonModel *jsonModel =[[JsonModel alloc]init];
```

So this instance of `JsonModel` is completely unrelated to the one you created previously (and set `jsonModel.idNumber`).

So ultimately what you need to do is keep the original `jsonModel` object that you created, and use that same object in the view controller.

Comment: Cool, can you show me a way to keep the original jsonModel? I will appreciate it. I was thinking creating a JsonModel property in handler, but not too sure if thats the best way to handle it.

Comment: Well that's certainly one way to do it. It don't know whether it's the *best* choice for your application though, as I don't know what your Handler is handling, or what the JsonModel represents.

Comment: Handler is the way I get json data, where as jsonModel is the way I am going to use to transfer data across my app so that way I am not flooding appdelegate. Is there another way besides jsonmodel property in handler?

Comment: You can put the data anywhere you like, such that its lifetime is long enough that it still exists when you want to use it. For example, something as simple as a global variable could work. Or, if you have some model object that represents the current state of data loaded from the server, you could put it in there. Or if you don't already have such a model object, now might be the time to consider creating one.